# File browser setting IMCE in CKeditor (using Wamp)

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I am using wamp for local testing. I installed drupal 7.12, added CKeditor module and IMCE. In "Settings" for CKeditor i am trying to set the "File browser" options to IMCE (IMCE is one op the options i can choose) but after hitting the "Save"-button i got a message telling me that the page has been re-initialised during loading of the page and ask me to check firewall settings and or i have internet connection. Of course my firewall settings are OK and i also have internet connection. It seems that IMCE (or CKeditor) is the only module causing this kind of problem; all the other modules are installing just fine and changing settings is no problem

Comment: Can you paste the entire error message verbatim on your question? Also can you check the dblog for more information (and also post that).

Comment: The errormessage is in dutch! I am using FF 10.0.1 error: De verbinding werd geherinitialiseerd
      
      
      
      
      
        
        
          De verbinding met de server werd geherinitialiseerd tijdens het laden van de pagina.
        

        
        

  Misschien is de website tijdelijk niet beschikbaar of overbelast. Probeer het 
    over enkele ogenblikken opnieuw.
  Controleer uw netwerkverbinding als u geen enkele pagina kunt laden.
  Verzeker u ervan dat Firefox toegang heeft tot het web als uw 
    computer of netwerk is beveiligd door een firewall of proxyserver.

Comment: Right so firefox (in dutch) is saying it cannot open the webpage. Sounds like your drupal install has issues. Can you visit the 'status report' page and tell me if everything is green, or whether there are some red items in there?

Comment: Everything green; no red items. I added several modules for an different website and the only module which is causing problems is IMCE in combination with CKeditor setting the filebrowser. As mentioned before I installed wamp for testing purposes locally. I didn't test it on the hosted website.

Comment: Have to ask some more grounding questions here: are you logged in as User #1? Do friendly URL's work for you (have you configured apache correctly)?

Comment: Friendly (Clean) URL's are working (rewrite_module has been activated). After reading the documentation again I am not sure that I have done everything that I should have. The documentation states that I have to change the httpd-file also but I never did that. Is there any info about that?  I am not logged in as User #1 (actually I don't know what you mean by "User #1").

Comment: User #1 is the first user in your 'users' table, typically this is the 'super user' for you site, and it bypasses all permissions etc.

Comment: I am user #1 (and the only user) and I do have administration rights. Do I have to change any settings in httpd.conf?